# how to set composite unique constraint in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

I'm quite new to ObjectBox.

I wonder if I can set up a constraint on multiple fields.

With the @Index annotation.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Write custom code to enforce custom conditions. There is no built-in support for composite indexes. https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/448

Use `@Index` to mark one or more properties to improve performance when doing checks, e.g. before inserting or updating. https://docs.objectbox.io/entity-annotations#property-indexes-with-index

Or use `@Unique`, a simple unique index, on one or more properties that causes inserts or updates to throw if the unique condition is violated.
https://docs.objectbox.io/entity-annotations#unique-constraints